# Difference between 夢想 and ドリームスケープ

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between these 2 terms?

Both refer to dreams but I want to know if ドリームスケープ may be referring to events that even though they've been dreamt, they are sure to happen in the future.
I'm looking for the meaning from the normal jananese point of view, not the technical stuff most people (even native speakers) don't know.

Comment: Not a native speaker but are you sure that most native speakers would even understand what ドリームスケープ is?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suppose so

Comment: I so much hope not.. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

夢想 is a literary suru-verb that means "to imagine like a dream" (as in "I dream of becoming a president").

ドリームスケープ is not a word recognized by ordinary Japanese people. Probably this is a direct transliteration of English [*dreamscape*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamscape) used as movie titles and such. But normal Japanese people will be only confused if you used it in a conversation.

Comment: Could you tell me what it means? (ドリームスケープ)

Comment: I saw it in a book. Two enemies become friends. I'm sure it was a dream (one of them suddenly wakes up) but I would like to know if it is the future (as the book ends there).

Comment: You're not interested in a minor definition even native speakers don't know, are you? Than it means absolutely nothing to me, and that's it. Of course I can guess it should be something related to a dream.

Comment: No, I thought it might ring a bell, but if it's that weird then it's ok. Thanks